# Cannot get AlertDialog response correctly because the app continues the execution

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In a my Activity I call a method that shows an alert dialog and returns a response according the button clicked on the `AlertDialog` and others checks (this method is in another class)

something like:

```
 public static boolean showAlertDialog(Context c,int param){
...
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(con);
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
        alert.setMessage(message);
        alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {
                        ...
                    }
                }


           );

        ....
        alert.show();
        return status;

    }
```

The problem is that when I call this method the code doesn't wait that the user do his operation on `AlertDialog`, but continues the execution.

so if in my activity do

```
boolean status=false;
status=Alerts.showAlertDialog(this);

if(status){
   //do this
}
else{
  //do that
}
```

always the else block is executed

How should I solve this?

Comment: @codeMagic I cannot do this, the AlertDialog is in another class and is reused for others operations according the passed param

Comment: Check this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906269/alertdialogs-setcancelablefalse-method-not-working

Comment: @Raghu the linked post doesn't answer my question

Comment: Sorry. I did not realize you wanted to block the main thread till user selects an option. Generally blocking the main thread is not a good idea (using wait or any other mechanism). Another approach is pass the activity that is calling show alert as a parameter and call a method from there by defining/implementing an interface and add what the subsequent code there. Hope this helps.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408756/create-a-general-class-for-custom-dialog-in-java-android/23408864#23408864

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest part is actually described in the Developer's Guide for Android, in the [Dialogs tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents).

It's pretty simple: you have to implement an interface on the Activity's side (`implements NoticeDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener`) and override the callback methods

```
@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    // User touched the dialog's positive button
    ...
}

@Override
public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    // User touched the dialog's negative button
    ...
}
```

The example I'm giving uses the `DialogFragment` which doesn't exactly fit your code. However, the implementation isn't that different for you, you just have to look up the corresponding interfaces (the [`OnDismissListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html) for instance)

You currently have this:

```
boolean status=false;
status=Alerts.showAlertDialog(this);

if(status){
   //do this
}
else{
  //do that
}
```

You'll have to eliminate the whole `if`. Change your Activity so it implements the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` interface

```
public class Blah extends Activity implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
```

and add the method

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
   if (which==DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE){
        //TODO: do your stuff
   }
}
```

finally, in your `Alerts.showDialog()` method change

```
 alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                    ...
                }
            }


       );
```

to

```
 alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,c);
```

If you do have an EditText, I'd have to assume you used the technique described in the [`AlertDialog` documentation Class Overview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html). If so, since you're receiving the dialog as a parameter, you would have to find the view in the Dialog with `findViewById` and extract the value that way.

Comment: Could you give me more details? the Dialogs are in another class,  how should I implement `OnDismissListener` to fix my problem ?

Comment: @AndreaF I added implementation details. You can also see some good examples, for instance here: http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example-code-tutorial/

Comment: Now your suggestion is more clear, but if the Dialog in `showDialog()` contains an `EditText` and I need to get the string input on positive button click, how could I do?

Comment: Your code doesn't show that case. However, if you do have an EditText, I'd have to assume you used the technique described in the AlertDialog documentation Class Overview(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html). If so, since you're receiving the dialog as a parameter, you would have to find the view in the Dialog with findViewById and extract the value that way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). This would allow you to post an event from the AlertDialog that you could handle in as many fragments or activities as you want.

Comment: there is another solution that doesn't force me to include a whole library only for this operation?