# Which button was clicked in a confirmation dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I've a problem to get the "result" of a custom confirmation dialog.
I built the following class:

```
public class MessageDialog {
  private static int result;

  public static final int OK = 0;
  public static final int CANCEL = 1;

  public static int showConfirmDialog(Context context, String message) {
    result = OK;

    AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    ad.setCancelable(false);
    ad.setMessage(message);
    ad.setTitle("Confirm");
    ad.setPositiveButton("Yes", new ButtonPressedListener());
    ad.setNegativeButton("No", new ButtonPressedListener());
    ad.create().show();

    return result;
  }

  private static class ButtonPressedListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
        result = OK;
      } else {
        result = CANCEL;
      }
      dialog.dismiss();
    }
  }
}
```

And call it from the MainActivity:

```
if (MessageDialog.showConfirmDialog(this, "Do you want to delete?") == MessageDialog.OK) {
  // yes button was clicked
} else {
  // no button was clicked
}
```

But it doesn't matter which button I tap, I always get the result that the yes button was clicked.

Answer (score -1):

That's because `show()` method shows alert asynchronously and therefore your `showConfirmDialog()` method always returns OK value before you can change it by tapping any button.
To avoid this you can handle different button behaviors in the `onClick()` method

For example:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
  switch(which) {
    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
      // yes button behavior
      break;
    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
      // no button behavior
      break;
  }

  dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean so can you give a small example please?

Comment: Ok, but in your example I have to know which code should be executed by clicking a button. But in my application I want to call the confirm dialog from different activities in different situations. So how the button handlers know what to execute?

Comment: @altralaser In your particular implementation you could for example implement different listeners and then pass them to the builder as needed. But if you want more solid approach take a look at the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408756/create-a-general-class-for-custom-dialog-in-java-android

Comment: After researching a lot I'm thinking the best way for me would be to define a callback interface and give it as an additional parameter to the showConfirmDialog method so the button handlers will have access to the right business logic, isn't it? It's a little bit different way like in standard Java toolkits but it works.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach. Hope my answers were somehow useful in your research