# How to set text to CustomAlertDialog?

Tags: android

i have a custom alert dialog , and i want to set message outer from her class

e.g = 
`alertDialog.setTextMessage("message");` but it's not working!

let me show you my full code :

AlertDialog Code :

```
public class AlertErrorDialog extends Dialog {

    LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView;
    TextView textMessage;
    String defaultMessage;

    public AlertErrorDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_alert_dialog);

        initWidgets();
    }

    private void initWidgets() {
        lottieAnimationView = findViewById(R.id.lottie);
        textMessage = findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
    }

    public AlertErrorDialog setTextMessage(String message){

        defaultMessage = message;

        if (textMessage != null && defaultMessage != null){
            textMessage.setText(defaultMessage);
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

How i call the custom alert dialog :

```
            AlertErrorDialog dialog = new AlertErrorDialog(EditProfileActivity.this);
            dialog.setTextMessage("apa aja");
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: set a break point and inspect the value of textMessage inside setTextMessage.  You have a null check on it so you'll never know if it's not finding it.  I suspect you didn't find the editText control.

Comment: checkout this :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41344309/3974530

Comment: your textview inside your dialog is null that's why msg is not set there

Comment: If my answer helps you then please mark as a right my answer from tick mark otherwise i'm gonna remove this answer brother : https://www.google.com/search?q=right+mark+as+an+answer+stackoverflow&sxsrf=ACYBGNQVsfXj9VeT9WRKWerxeSRoAMe2uQ:1579936139192&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQk-DimJ7nAhWBc30KHdm9CGAQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1517&bih=730#imgrc=9_JN49MpzDykBM:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your code try now

```
public class AlertErrorDialog extends Dialog {

    LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView;
    TextView textMessage;
    String defaultMessage;

    public AlertErrorDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_alert_dialog);

        initWidgets();
    }

    private void initWidgets() {
        lottieAnimationView = findViewById(R.id.lottie);
        textMessage = findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
        textMessage.setText(defaultMessage);
    }

    public AlertErrorDialog setTextMessage(String message){

        defaultMessage = message;

        //if (textMessage != null && defaultMessage != null){
        // textMessage.setText(defaultMessage);
        // }

        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, It may be helpful for you.

```
public static void alertDialogShow(Context context, String message)
    {
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                // Handle your on click action
          } 
        }); 
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

And call this in your activity class:-

```
Utils.alertDialogShow(YourActivity.this,"Your Error Message")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   MainActivity.java
   ==================

        Helper.showDialog(MainActivity.this,"message");



   Helper.java
   ===========

 public static void showDialog(Context context,String message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setTitle("With RatingBar");
    View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_with_ratingbar,         
    null);
    final RatingBar ratingBar = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    builder.setView(dialogLayout);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Rating is " +      
               ratingBar.getRating(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.show(); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not seeing your message is your `setTextMessage` method is being called before the `onCreate`. And hence your textview is not yet initialized when you try to set text on it in `setTextMessage` method.

If you put a delay of some milliseconds in your `setTextMessage`. You will get the result.

But putting all the code of `onCreate` method in the constructor will also do a job for you.